# Godot 3.5 parse_input_event resets mouse position

Tags: godot, joystick

I have a point and click game for which I'm adapting joypad controls. I want the mouse to move with thumbsticks and trigger mouse click with joystick A button.

I can move the mouse using `get_viewport().warp_mouse(mouse_pos)`

I can trigger mouse click creating new mousebuttonevent and parsing it

```
var left_click = InputEventMouseButton.new()
left_click.pressed = pressed
left_click.button_index = button_index  
left_click.position =  get_viewport().get_mouse_position()
print("emulated: ", left_click.as_text())
Input.parse_input_event(left_click)
```

But after I call `Input.parse_input_event(left_click)` and move thumsticks again it has reset the mouse position to 0, 0.

Here is the full code. I'm quite confused.

````
var mouse_pos

func _ready():
    $ColorRect/Button.connect("pressed", self, "pressed")

func pressed():
    print("button pressed")
            

func _input(event):
    if event is InputEventMouseButton:
        print("from _input: ", event.as_text())

    elif event is InputEventJoypadButton:
        if event.is_action_pressed("a_button"):
            print("pressed A")
            emulate_click(BUTTON_LEFT , true)
#       elif event.is_action_released("ui_accept"): 
#           print("released A")
#           emulate_click(BUTTON_LEFT, false)
                        
            
func emulate_click(button_index, pressed):
    var left_click = InputEventMouseButton.new()
    left_click.pressed = pressed
    left_click.button_index = button_index  
    left_click.position =  get_viewport().get_mouse_position()
    print("emulated: ", left_click.as_text())
    Input.parse_input_event(left_click)
#   get_viewport().warp_mouse(cached_mouse_pos)
#   pointer.global_position = previous_mouse_pos


func _process(delta):   
    var direction: Vector2
    
    direction.x = Input.get_action_strength ("t_right", true) - Input.get_action_strength ("t_left", true)
    direction.y = Input.get_action_strength ("t_down", true) - Input.get_action_strength ("t_up", true)

    if abs(direction.x) == 1 and abs(direction.y) == 1:
        direction = direction.normalized()      

    var thumbstick_sensitivity = 1000
    var movement = thumbstick_sensitivity * direction * delta
    if (movement): 
        mouse_pos = get_viewport().get_mouse_position() + movement
        print(mouse_pos)
        get_viewport().warp_mouse(mouse_pos)``` 

Any ideas are super welcome!
````

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the global position (`global_pos`) of the new `InputEventMouseButton` object.

This is due to the L332-L344 of `input_default.cpp` in Godot's source code, which read:

```
    Ref<InputEventMouseButton> mb = p_event;

    if (mb.is_valid()) {
        if (mb->is_pressed()) {
            mouse_button_mask |= (1 << (mb->get_button_index() - 1));
        } else {
            mouse_button_mask &= ~(1 << (mb->get_button_index() - 1));
        }

        Point2 pos = mb->get_global_position();
        if (mouse_pos != pos) {
            set_mouse_position(pos);
        }
```

If you don't set the global position, it defaults to `(0,0)` which is why you're seeing this unexpected behaviour.